# ELSE IF not working " unexpected '{' in line..."

Tags: php, if-statement

trying to do some easy if-statements but getting "unexpected {". I've put a comment in the code where the error occurs. Any hints?

```
Code:

<?php
if(isset($_GET['tax'])) {
$tax = $_GET['tax'];

if ($tax < "8900")
 {
    echo "Du behöver inte betala någon skatt";
    }
    elseif ($tax > "8900" && $tax < "198700")
    {
        echo "Du behöver att betala 100 SEK i skatt";
    }
    else ($tax >= "198700")
    { //ERROR OCCURS HERE
        echo "You have to pay (100+(0.2*$tax)) i skatt";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: `else` can't have a condition.

Comment: Come on. Why so many down-votes to a newbie ? Don't be rude.

Comment: Uh great. Thanks to downvote nagging, there's four upvotes now? Anyone care to elaborate why syntax error questions now get encouraged when there's no discernable research or attempts on OPs part to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

```
else ($tax >= "198700")
```

is not a valid statement. You need to either use:

```
elseif ($tax >= "198700")
```

or:

```
else // ($tax >= "198700")
```

That latter is okay assuming you fix the problem of what happens at 8900 (currently it matches neither of the first two). You probably wanted:

```
elseif ($tax >= "8900" && $tax < "198700")
```

And a couple of other things to at least check:

- I'm not *entirely* certain why you switched from Swedish to English in the final `echo` - that seems incongruous.
- As mentioned previously, you appear to have a "hole" at 8900.
- Not sure whether *string* comparisons are going to work properly here. PHP *might* handle it okay but, in some circumstances, `"10"` is less than `"2"`.
- I'm also pretty certain your string interpolation won't work as you expect. You probably need to calculate it outside the context of the string (`$pay = $tax / 5 + 100;`) and interpolate *that* (`echo "Du behöver att betala $pay i skatt";`).

Answer (score 1):

An **`else`** statement cannot contain a condition.

Change your `else ($tax >= "198700")` to `elseif($tax >= "198700")`

Answer (score 1):

The `else` statement should not contain the Condition.

It works as Default block when all conditions becomes FALSE.

See Doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

If you need to evaluate the block on codition means,

```
else ($tax >= "198700")
```

change this to:

```
else if ($tax >= "198700")
```